# Delphi 2010: Where is DockForm.pas?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I have to upgrade an old Delphi3 project to Delphi2010.

It uses a unit named **DockForm**, but I cannot find it anywhere in Delphi2010.

It is present in the old Delphi3 install CD as **uDockForm**, but it should be also found in D2010, because own D2010 source files use it (for example, **\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\7.0\source\ToolsAPI\ToolsApi.pas**).

Where is **DockForm.pas** or equivalent for D2010?

Thanks

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There is no DockForm.pas in D2010 sources but you can use it in your application. Just add "designide" in Project -> Options -> Packages -> Build with runtime packages. Or add it to "require" section if you want to use it in a package.

Comment: You cannot redistribute that package. It is designed to be used only for design-time component/property editors or IDE add-ins.

Comment: What is the name of this package ?

Comment: The package is DesignIde